# Biblatex, Footnote Citations and Numbers in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I'm writing a document where I'm using `biblatex` (with BibTeX as back-end). In my document I would like to have citations as footnotes, "normal" footnotes containing text and at the end a consolidated bibliography of the references my document contains.

There is only one, quite small, issue. I would like the final bibliography to also display the footnote number associated with the citation. How do I accomplish that?

The references at the end should then appear as:

> (footnote number) (author) (title) (year)

Here's a simple example of my problem:

Generated document: http://fuskbugg.se/dl/ySqEUE/test.pdf

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @book{Foo,
        title={Book title1},
        author={Author1},
        year= {Year1},
    }
    @book{Bar,
        title={Book title2},
        author={Author2},
        year= {Year2},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

This is some text\footcite{Foo}, with\footnote{"Normal" footnotes also appear.} footnotes.\footcite{Bar}

\newpage

How can I make the footnote number associated with the reference be printed along with the reference? (First entry should be numbered 1 and second numbered 3.)

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Is there a special reason why you are using BibTeX instead of Biber? It appears you are using an outdated version of `biblatex`. The newer version of `biblatex` (2.x) has the default option `backend=biber`. To help you more effective I recommend that you have a updated LaTeX distribution.

Comment: What will happen if you use `\footcite{foo}` more often? How do you expect the output in the references?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I guess the OP wants the number of the *first*  footnote.

Comment: @lockstep: And the option `\nocite` isn't explained here ;-). I think the question might become really complex.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel 1. I'm using bibtex for no special reason. I just started writing a document and bibtex seemed to work just fine. 2. Multiple citations of the same source is an interesting issue. I'm pretty much neutral on this issue but I'm kinda leaning towards that multiple occurrences in the bibliography would be the best solution. (the solution presented by lockstep is good though) 3. As for \nocite that's nothing I have utilized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following must be done:

- Amend the `cite:full` bibmacro so that it will also store the current footnote number in a new macro whose name uses the `entrykey` of the current entry;
- Use the `numeric` bibstyle and the option `sorting=none`;
- Change the `labelnumber` format so that it displays the meaning of the "footnote number"  macro of the current entry.

Note that the bibliography "labels" will be ambiguous if you cite several entries for the first time in the same footnote.

(EDIT: The OP stated that he/she uses *BibTeX* as backend, but the current `biblatex` version [2.2] willl by default [as in the OP's MWE] use *Biber*. That said, the following solution will also work with BibTeX if one adds the appropriate `backend=bibtex` package option.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[citestyle=verbose,bibstyle=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\makeatletter

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
%  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}% DELETED
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}% NEW
  \csxdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@footnotenumber}{\the\value{footnote}}% NEW
}% NEW

\DeclareFieldFormat{prefixnumber}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\csuse{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@footnotenumber}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Foo,
        title={Book title1},
        author={Author1},
        year= {Year1},
    }
    @book{Bar,
        title={Book title2},
        author={Author2},
        year= {Year2},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

This is some text\footcite{Foo}, with\footnote{"Normal" footnotes also appear.}
footnotes.\footcite{Bar}

How can I make the footnote number associated with the reference be printed along
with the reference? (First entry should be numbered 1 and second numbered 3.)

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I try your solutions, but with error: File 'filecontents.sty' not found. How can they fix it?

Comment: @jafan a) Remove all auxiliary files and compile again. b) Be sure to compile my example as-is.

Comment: Without effect. a) copy your solution b) cmd> xelatex exam.tex -> error  File 'filecontents.sty' not found. Should I create yet another file?

Comment: @lockstep Thank you! This solution works great. You really did me a favour there.

Comment: @jafan " 'filecontents.sty' not found." Almost certainly means that the package filecontents is not installed on your computer.

Comment: Do you know how to modify this so that mpfootnotes appear with the correct numbering?  The following line prints out based on footnote value, but within a minipage environment this doesn't work.

    \csxdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@footnotenumber}{\the\value{footnote}}

Within my environment I am using:

    setcounter{mpfootnote}{\value{footnote}}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}

and

    \setcounter{footnote}{\value{mpfootnote}

Comment: @lockstep I wonder how to use it when I need also use `style=verbose-ibid` or `style=verbose-ibid`. These macros drives me mad :(