# Biblatex with BiBTeX backend, Same Footnumbers and Bibliography Numbers, while different Style in Footnote and Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, footnotes

fellow TeX-enthusiasts!

I'm using Biblatex with the BibTeX backend (Please don't tell me I need to use Biber, it don't work an my system for some reason...)

I have two problems, which I can solve seperately, but not together.

1. I need Author+Title+Year in footnote

Solution: [Only Author+Title+Year in footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215512/only-authortitleyear-in-footnote)

2. I need a correct numbering for citing. It should be the same as for footnotes. So when I cite page 10 Source 1,... Source 2, page 20 Source 1, Source 3

I get my footnotnumbers:
1,2,3,4

but Bibliographynumbers:
1,2,3

A Solution would be:
[Biblatex, Footnote Citations and Numbers in Bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73776/biblatex-footnote-citations-and-numbers-in-bibliography)

The Problem is, that the second one does only work with citestyle=verbose

Short example(with copied code from two links above)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose,citestyle=authortitle,bibstyle=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\makeatletter

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
%  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}% DELETED
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}% NEW
  \csxdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@footnotenumber}{\the\value{footnote}}% NEW
}% NEW

\DeclareFieldFormat{prefixnumber}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\csuse{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@footnotenumber}}

\makeatother
    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \xapptobibmacro{cite}{\setunit{\nametitledelim}\printfield{year}}{}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @book{this,
        title={Book title1},
        author={Author1},
        year= {Year1},
    }
    @book{that,
        title={Book title2},
        author={Author2},
        year= {Year2},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

This is some text\footcite[141]{this}, with same \footcite[151]{this} footnotes.\footcite{that}

\newpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

P.S. - This Page helped me so many times, thak you all!

Comment: Welcome! I'm not fallow at all, I'll have you know!