# Numbers in bibliography cannot be switched on

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, biber

Using `beamer`, `XeLaTeX` and `biber`, I have single citations in footnotes and a full bibliography on the last slide.

I would like to have numbered entries in the full bibliography but using

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
```

did not work. There is simply no number in front of the entries in the bibliography.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}{test_bib.bib} 
    @book{Peter1, 
        author={Peter Muller}, 
        title={My life as Peter Mueller}, 
        address={Peterstown}, 
        publisher={Petersen family},
        year={2017}
    } 
    @article{Klaus1,
        author = {Peter, Klaus and Petersen, Peter},
        title = {A research article about Peter Mueller},
        journal = {Intern. Journal on Science},
        year = {2018},
        volume = {33},
        pages = {000007},
        doi = {10.10}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,
            autocite=footnote,
            backend=biber,
           ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test_bib.bib}

% I thought this would switch on numbers in bibliography
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

% change appearance of citations in footnotes
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield{journaltitle}%
      \setunit{\space}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printdate}%
    }
  }{}%
  \ifentrytype{book}{
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
      \setunit{\space}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printdate}%
    }%
  }{}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Two columns on this page}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Some text in the first column
              \item More text\footnotemark
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \footcitetext{Peter1}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Guess what: more text\footnotemark
              \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \footcitetext{Klaus1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I compile with `xelatex`, `biber`,  `xelatex`,  `xelatex` and the compiled bibliography looks as follows:

[image: bibliography]

My question: how do I get numbers in the bibliography (and what is the error in my case) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the style of your bibliography. Change

```
style=authortitle
```

to

```
style=numeric
```

In your case with your using of citing with footnotes you should use:

```
 citestyle=authortitle, % <============================================
 bibstyle=numeric,
```

With the following complete code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}{test_bib.bib} 
    @book{Peter1, 
        author={Peter Muller}, 
        title={My life as Peter Mueller}, 
        address={Peterstown}, 
        publisher={Petersen family},
        year={2017}
    } 
    @article{Klaus1,
        author = {Peter, Klaus and Petersen, Peter},
        title = {A research article about Peter Mueller},
        journal = {Intern. Journal on Science},
        year = {2018},
        volume = {33},
        pages = {000007},
        doi = {10.10}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[%style=numeric, % authortitle <=============================
  citestyle=authortitle, % <============================================
  bibstyle=numeric, % <=================================================
  autocite=footnote,
  backend=biber,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test_bib.bib}

% I thought this would switch on numbers in bibliography
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

% change appearance of citations in footnotes
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield{journaltitle}%
      \setunit{\space}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printdate}%
    }
  }{}%
  \ifentrytype{book}{
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
      \setunit{\space}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printdate}%
    }%
  }{}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Two columns on this page}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Some text in the first column
              \item More text\footnotemark
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \footcitetext{Peter1}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Guess what: more text\footnotemark
              \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \footcitetext{Klaus1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for you immediate answer! Doing as you suggested works but also destroys my footnote citations: when compiling there is a warning `Macro 'cite:title' undefined` and only numbers are shown in the footnote citations... (it also does not help to replace `renewbibmacro` with `newbibmacro`)

Comment: the code was inspired from a few threads I found on this site (is it somehow weird or confusing code?). I just figured out the solution: `citestyle=authortitle` and `bibstyle=numeric`. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction - is it possible that you update your answer accordingly?

Comment: @Alf I don't want to be a spoilsport, but please keep in mind that there is absolutely no guarantee that the footnote number and the label number of your citations in the bibliography coincide. Just cite `Klaus1` *before* `Peter1` and compare the footnote and bibliography. This can be made worse by sprinkling in other normal footnotes or citing a work again.

Comment: @moewe ouch, thanks for the warning! I guess I have to think of something else then....

Comment: @Alf There are a lot of questions about cite styles like this on this site, because it is quite tricky to pull off. I myself am not particularly fond of mixing numeric and verbose-like styles in such a way, but I can see where people are coming from. If you really like that sort of thing I would try with something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45406/35864 from Audrey's answer. With her answers you can usually be sure that stuff has been thought through.

Comment: @moewe yes, there are indeed quite a few of those questions (I also added a few ;-). Thanks for pointing me to that post, I guess I overlooked it so far.

Comment: @moewe just for the sake of completeness, this one seems to solve the problem with the footnote number -- label number confusion: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73776/biblatex-footnote-citations-and-numbers-in-bibliography